# Can I sort a line over bar chart?

Tags: highcharts, lineplusbarchart

[When I try to sort the second graph by the rep names, the names remain static while the bars move. The graph thus shows incorrect data. Need help with resolving the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x48mh.png)

Tried sorting the graph by the y axis, we are unable to sort the graph by the rep names

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and provide a code, so that I could work on it?